# Python package published with poetry is not found after install

Tags: python, git, publish, pypi, python-poetry

In the last few days, I was working on a python module. Until now, I used `poetry` as a packages management tool in many other projects, but it is my first time wanting to publish a package to PyPI.

I was able to run the `poetry build` and `poetry publish` commands. I was also able to also install the published package:

```
$ pip3 install git-profiles
Collecting git-profiles
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0e/e7/bac9027effd1e34a5b5718f2b35c0b28b3d67f3809e2f2981b6c7b58963e/git_profiles-1.1.0-py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: git-profiles
Successfully installed git-profiles-1.1.0
```

However, right after the install, I am not able to run my package:

```
$ git-profiles --help
git-profiles: command not found
```

My project has the following structure:

```
git-profiles/
├── src/
│   ├── commands/
│   ├── executor/
│   ├── git_manager/
│   ├── profile/
│   ├── utils/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── git_profiles.py
└── tests
```

I tried to work with different scripts configurations in the pyproject.toml file but I've never been able to make it work after install.

```
[tool.poetry.scripts]
poetry = "src:git_profiles.py"
```

or

```
[tool.poetry.scripts]
git-profile = "src:git_profiles.py"
```

I don't know if this is a python/pip path/version problem or I need to change something in the configuration file.

If it is helpful, [this](https://github.com/popadi/git-profiles) is the GitHub repository I'm talking about. The package is also published [on PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/git-profiles/).

Answer (score 2):

Poetry's `scripts` sections wraps around the [console script definition](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html#the-console-scripts-entry-point) of `setuptools`. As such, the  entrypoint name and the call path you give it need to follow the exact same rules.

In short, a console script does more or less this from the shell:

```py
import my_lib  # the module isn't called src, that's just a folder name
               # the right name to import is whatever you put at [tool.poetry].name

my_lib.my_module.function()
```

Which, if given the name `my-lib-call` (the name can be the same as your module, but it doesn't need to be) would be written like this:

```
[tool.poetry.scripts]
my-lib-call = "my_lib.my_module:function"
```

Adapted to your project structure, the following should do the job:

```
[tool.poetry.scripts]
git-profile = "git-profiles:main"
```